# avcodec_find_decoder() - segmentation fault

Tags: c, ffmpeg

This is my simple ffmpeg code.

I`m reading a .ogg from the file.

```
      #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
      #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
      int main(int argc, char **argv){
      av_register_all();
      avcodec_register_all();
      static const char *src_filename = NULL;
      static AVFormatContext *input_format_context = NULL;
      int ret; int error;
    
      
      src_filename = argv[1];
    
      //open audio file
      if ((error = avformat_open_input(&input_format_context, src_filename, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open input file\n");
            return ret;
        }else{
          fprintf(stderr, "open file +  \n");
        }
```

and then call av_format_stream_info function.

```
  // find stream info 
  error = avformat_find_stream_info(input_format_context, NULL);
  if (ret < 0) {
     av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find stream information\n");
    }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "find stream +  \n");
      }
```

everything is ok so far. but now when i call the avcodec_find_decoder function i get the segmentation fault.

```
for (int i=0; i < input_format_context->nb_streams; i++) 
            {
          fprintf(stderr, "1.1\n");
                AVStream *stream = input_format_context->streams[0];
          fprintf(stderr, "1.2\n");
          
          AVCodec *dec = avcodec_find_decoder(stream->codecpar->codec_id);
          fprintf(stderr, "1.3\n");
            }
        
      return 0;
      }
```

And this is my cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(decode_encode)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS")

find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

find_path(AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR libavformat/avformat.h)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat)

find_path(AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR libavutil/avutil.h)
find_library(AVUTIL_LIBRARY avutil)

find_path(AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR libavdevice/avdevice.h)
find_library(AVDEVICE_LIBRARY avdevice)

add_executable(readFewFrame readFewFrame.c)

target_include_directories(readFewFrame PRIVATE ${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR} ${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(readFewFrame PRIVATE ${AVCODEC_LIBRARY} ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY} ${AVUTIL_LIBRARY} ${AVDEVICE_LIBRARY})
```

what exactly could be the cause of this error?

Comment: You're calling `error = avformat_find_stream_info(input_format_context, NULL);`, but you're testing the value of `ret` on the next line. Check `error` instead.

Comment: i've fixed that but it's not the problem. the code stuck between 1.2 and 1.3. @vmt

Comment: Are you sure `stream` is not NULL?

Comment: Also - most likely unrelated but you're always using the first stream in the loop where your code implies your intention is to go through all of the streams. At any rate, you could compile with debug symbols and take a look at it with a debugger.

Comment: yes sir. I've already checked it. and tested with some other audios. it's same. "streams[0]" is just for testing. when it is "streams[i]" I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure which version you're linking against, but instead of the `codecpar` member in `AVStream`, you could try the deprecated `codec`.